# Backend for RESTful (JSON)

Tags: java, rest, webclient, backend

I have a question regarding RESTful client implementation.

At this moment I have developed the server using RESTeasy and EJB. Method return JSON in much case. And now we are starting backend development(WEB). And can't select a framework for this, that supports authorization, authentication...

Could you suggest a pattern, framework, approach etc..

Comment: I think about, maybe would be perfect use only jquery to request... only what about data verification...

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for a Java web framework that fits your existing technology (EJB) you should take a look at JSF and WebBeans (note though that JSF does not expose RESTful URLs for its actions/controllers).

However since you also mentioned REST I guess you just want a backend framework for your  services that can handle user security and auth. In this case you should take a look at spring (in particular spring-security and spring-web). Most **JAX-RS** implementations have good support for spring, although I should mention that spring itself has a splendid REST framework that of cause works very well with their other offerings.

If on the other hand you want a framework that can handle security in the context of a EJB application that exposes a RESTful service, then you are in a tough spot. RESTful applications are meant to keep most of the state at the client, in contrast to most EJB apps that frequently uses state-full session beans. You can integrate JAX-RS with stateless or singleton EJBs and then either use spring-security to handle the security/auth or use the  `<security-constraint>` in the web.xml as described [here](http://www.butonic.de/2010/06/18/a-simple-jax-rs-security-context-example-in-glassfish/)

Comment: I'm not sure that I want use EJB for web. I inclined to use RESTful URls. But how it's doing so that in result I would not anti-pattern I don't now. May be you know some link to learn by me... Or may be you suggest to use EJB and fogote about REST... (note: I developed REST for other purpose but I have it now think about to use it). What is your opinion?

Comment: I understood your comment about EJB as you already have a EJB backend in place, in which case JSF is a good fit. If however you do not have any EJBs then stay away from them and develop your backend using Spring. This will make it easy to do server side auth and security. As for what framework to use when writing the frontend for the restful services I would go with JQuery or perhaps ExtJS 4.

Comment: Thanks for advance! I have not experience with Spring and the same time have realized server part based on EJB. So I incline to not use Spring. Could you suggest me pattern which better to use EJB + WEB